# How to check if an EditText was changed or not?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need to know if an <kbd>EditText</kbd> was changed or not, not whether or not the user inputted some text in the field, but only the if <kbd>String</kbd> was changed.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You need a 
`TextWatcher`

See it here in action:

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_ID);
text.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);


private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
  }

  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
  }

  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
          int count) {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you change your mind to listen to the keystrokes you can use OnKeyListener

```
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box); 

    et.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            //key listening stuff
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But Johe's answer is what you need.

Answer (score 7):

This actually worked for me

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_ID);

text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        if(your_string.equals(String.valueOf(s))) {
           //do something
        }else{
            //do something 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Implement a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).  It gives you three methods, `beforeTextChanged`, `onTextChanged`, and `afterTextChanged`.  The last method shouldn't be called until something changes anyway, so that's a good thing to use for it.