# How to know my edit texts are changed are not, when edittext are more than twenty

Tags: android, android-edittext

when i have `only few edit texts` using textchangeListener or compare texts to find the text is changed or not if i have `more than 20 edittext` how to know the edit text is changed or not

i found  nearly same asked here 1. [How to check if an EditText was changed or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391891/how-to-check-was-edittext-changed-or-not) 2. [Knowing when Edit text is done being edited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099814/knowing-when-edit-text-is-done-being-edited) this is helpful  ...There is any simple way to do this.

```
String temp = "aa";
    if(temp.equals(edittext.getText().toString()) {
        Log.e("Not Change",temp);
    } else {
            Log.e("Changed Value",edittext.getText().toString());
    }
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: if u are having array of EditText then using for loop you can achive this...

Comment: @ADT any references....

Comment: no... but I am for sure that u can achive by this see my answer i ll post after testing

Comment: can you post your code ...?

Comment: @ADT look at my code this what i tried previous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like below:

EDIT:

```
n1I1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etN1I1);
n1I2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etN1I2);
n1I3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etN1I3);


 TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
 Toast.makeText(yourActivity.this,"changed",0).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
};

ArrayList<EditText> firstList = new ArrayList<EditText>();
firstList.add(n1I1);
firstList.add(n1I2);
firstList.add(n1I3);

for(int i=0;i<firstList.size();i++)
{
 firstList.get(i).addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
}
```

Comment: the temp value i provide for sample ...i want to compare the new edit text value with previous value...

Comment: it doesnt show the changed toast...that is when delete the old records and insert new records then only the toast shown

Answer (score 2):

please make a common method for all Edittext like this:

```
private void checkEditText(String temp, EditText edittext){
 if(temp.equals(edittext.getText().toString()) {
     Log.e("Not Change",temp);
 } else {
     Log.e("Changed Value",edittext.getText().toString());
 }
```

}

use a switch case for calling this method for individual Edittext.

Let me know if u get any problem.